# How to convert a bash script to tcsh

Tags: bash, tcsh

```
function history_to_syslog {
    declare command
    remoteaddr="`who am i`"
    pwd="`pwd`"
    command=$(fc -ln -0)
    if [ "$command" != "$old_command" ]; then
        logger -p local2.notice -t bash -i ? "$USER : $remoteaddr" \
        "Command : $command  Directory : $pwd"
    fi
    old_command=$command
}
trap history_to_syslog DEBUG
```

How do I change to change the bash scripts to tcsh?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: You might want to look at a different approach to solve the problem. tcsh does not have 'trap ... DEBUG' to process commands. Consider using 'set -vx', which will print each executed command, and then send complete log to syslog

Comment: @YosephJ : This is a bit like a "How to convert a Java-program into COBOL" question. From knowing, what the program is supposed to do, just write it from scratch in the new language - especially if the target programming language is quite different from the original one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change a script from bash to csh, you first need to learn about the differences between the different shell environments.
For example study this guide on [http://hyperpolyglot.org](http://hyperpolyglot.org/unix-shells).
You might learn, that the vast majority is equivalent. Some syntax can directly be translated into each other. However, some syntax is too specific to its shell to be directly translatable.

Your next step is to identify which parts of your code can be translated directly, and which parts do not have a 1-to-1 translation - and therefore need another implementation csh.